# Is OrientDB suitable for social network analytics?

Tags: social-networking, traversal, orientdb

I'm trying to use OrientDB for social network analytics, but is it suitable for that?
In my application, there might be billions of nodes and relationship, since OrientDB support distributed servers, so I think scalability wouldn't be a problem.

I also need to get friends of one person, mutual friends of two persons, friends recommadations and merge two nodes in case that they are actually one person. It seems that OrientDB traverse is not that suitable for these queries.

Is OrientDB suitable for my application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Course it is! OrientDB SQL Traverse command is powerful, but you can always use [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) to do such things.

Comment: Currently, OrientDB traverse support depth first algorithm only, breadth first traverse is useful for social network, I want to know neighborhood friends first. Could you give me an example for how can I   get mutual friends between two persons?